# boost::shared_ptr error at end of class

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr, reset

```
class SomeData{};
typedef boost::shared_ptr<SomeData> data_ptr;

class ABC {
public:   ABC(){}

          ~ABC(){cached_ptr.reset(); }

          data_ptr get_ptr() {data_ptr x; return x;} // it does work and returns a data_ptr

          bool someWork(data_ptr& passed_ptr) {
            if(cached_ptr == NULL) {
              cached_ptr = get_ptr();
              passed_ptr.reset(new SomeData(*cached_ptr));
            }
            return true;
          }

          data_ptr otherWork() {
            if(cached_ptr == NULL) { 
                cached_ptr = get_ptr();
                data_ptr local_ptr = boost::make_shared<SomeData>(*cached_ptr);
            }
            return data_ptr;   // after some more work
         }

private:  data_ptr cached_ptr;   // class member
};
```

The above is a simplification of some code that I am trying to get to work.

It did, until I added the "cached_ptr", the ability to cache data between successive calls to avoid calling get_ptr() every single time (it can be fairly big).

Note: I have boost::make_shared and reset() - I experimented with both to see if the error was caused by the copy. It didn't make a difference (As expected).

I already have google test unit tests in place - and when I added the cached_ptr, google test has been giving me errors of the "GTEST_HAS_SEH" kind.

```
"unknown file: error: SEH exception with code 0xc000005 thrown in the test body."
```

The error occurs on the destructor: `cached_ptr.reset()`;

Visual Studio says:

```
    "First-chance exception at 0x00ceba41 in myFile_gtest.exe: 0xC0000005: 
Access violation reading location 0xfeeefeee."
```

It occurs without it as well (initially I didn't even place a reset(), I thought that a shared pointer kills itself when it runs out of scope.

What could be my problem ?

boost 1.47

Thank you.

Comment: Your function `void bool someWork(data_ptr& passed_ptr)` should return a `bool`, but does not return anything. That is undefined behavior. Could you post the real code, or something that represents it close enough for a meaningful analysis?

Comment: Also, what is the definition of `SomeData`?

Comment: Another thing: the problem may be in the way you are creating or working with `ABC`. I guess you should prepare an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: SomeData is a class defined in a dependent project - contains quite a few things, among which an std::vector<SomeData*> - it is a special kind of tree. I didn't think that it is relevant... This should work with any kind of class ?

Comment: Well, if your `SomeData` does not respect the Rule of Three, for instance, copy-constructing it may lead to troubles like double deletions. I also see that you are holding child nodes through raw pointers, which suggests that you are doing some manual memory management with `new` and `delete`, and that's pretty error-prone

Comment: It does seem likely that make_shared is creating a pointer pointing at the same data - which means, I didn't manage to copy it after all. I will have to get a copy constructor, get the data from one pointer, copy it, and create a pointer with that data. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Andy Prowl noticed (in comments to my question), the class the pointer was pointing at did not contained a copy constructor.

boost::make_shared requires a copy constructor in order to make a copy...

In its absence it pointed at the same data, so when the original pointer went out of scope, the cached one lost its point (even though, when debugging, it looked like it still had it...)

Adding a copy constructor for `SomeData` solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef boost::shared_ptr<SomeData> data_ptr;

data_ptr get_ptr() { data_ptr x; return x; }

  cached_ptr = get_ptr();
  passed_ptr.reset(new SomeData(*cached_ptr));
```

---

`get_ptr()` returned a `NULL` pointer, and then you dereferenced it.

You never set `cached_ptr` to anything other than `NULL`, but that's a separate issue.

Comment: Sorry, I thought my comment explained that get_ptr() does a lot of work and then returns the results of that work. It is not null, and the code does work without the cached_ptr. The comments from Andy Prowl show that I did not have a copy constructor - the class I was using did not have one, and I thought I might not need it. The addition of a copy constructor solved the problem.

Comment: @Thalia Ah, thanks for the clarification. I understand now. I thought you meant _work_ (verb) but you actually meant _work_ (noun).

Answer (score 0):

you dereferences null pointer (*cached_ptr) in the following fragment:

```
cached_ptr = get_ptr();
passed_ptr.reset(new SomeData(*cached_ptr));
```

so your program becomes illformed. in this case you cannot do any expectation.

Comment: Sorry, I thought my comment explained that get_ptr() does a lot of work and then returns the results of that work (as a "data_ptr", created in that function). It is not null, and the code does work without the cached_ptr. The comments from Andy Prowl show that I did not have a copy constructor - the class I was using did not have one, and I thought I might not need it. The addition of a copy constructor solved the problem.